transparent looking shading not working
hello i need some help
in the tutorial the eye the transmission to 1 and the alpha to 1 leads to cristal apeareance i need the pink ball inside the cristal ball but to look translucid on evee actually i dont know what is going on it is not happening

this is what i need to achieve, i tried using transmission 1 and alpha default but failed, in the tutorial im watching they achieve that effect by just setting to 1 the transmission
kudos to anyone to help me on this quest

blend file
https://workupload.com/file/qGXvXQh8Q7t

I strongly suggest you write this in your native language with full proper punctuation, and then machine translate it.

Does this tutorial use EEVEE, or Cycles? Refraction is about as different as the two engines get, EEVEE being the harder one to make refractive things look right in. You may want to add the tutorial link.

sorry for my bad punctuation i was stressed out, i will correct it, the tutorial was from cgboost, i ve bought it, the engine is evee, in cycles its working, the guy just literally just tweaked the transmission set to 1.000 and its done but in my blender is not working, am i doing something wrong?

In the Render panel activate Screen Space Reflections and Refractions, and in the Material > Settings activate Raytrace Refraction?

Does this answer your question? The Transmission weight = 1 in Blender 4.1 BSDF Node doesn't allow see through the object. As @moonboots said, you have to change some settings to make refraction work in EEVEE while in Cycles it works "out of the box". See my linked answer on the other question for details.

thank you guys, should i delete the question?

@John carmack No you don't need
